# save facebook object variables

Tags: php, facebook

How can do I use:
              'https://graph.facebook.com/".$data["user_id"]."?access_token=".$data["oauth_token"]'

After the user accepts my application I can go to this page and see their information.  I need a function that will return these values from this page into variables that I can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the official Facebook PHP SDK, a set of PHP classes allowing you to interact with the Graph API.

https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk

If you really want to do it by hand: the Facebook API returns it's data in the JSON format.

In PHP you can first grab the content of the url ( really easy way: $result = file_get_contents('https://.....'); ) and then turn it into a regular structured php array with

```
$data = json_decode($result);
```

Comment: for some reason i cannot get the array using the json_decode, do I need to include something to the page to use this fucntion?